# forwarding DHCP packets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp

I've got this configuration:

```
WRouter ->(by wifi) Computer1
```

And I want to add another computer (`computer2`) connected by cable to `computer1`.
Is it possible then to configure `computer1` to forward all packets from/to `computer2` with DHCP packets too? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called DHCP Relay there is an [agent for that!](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhcrelay)

Answer (score 1):

As for **DHCP** your going to have a difficult time. You might have to start a **DCHP** server on computer 1's Ethernet Connection.

You should checkout this **[question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/connecting-to-a-network-via-another-pc)**. It seems to be related to what you are trying to do. Except that computer 2 and computer 1 IP's are manually set....