# Connecting to network via another pc. Without requiring credentials

Tags: linux, networking

My Question is regarding [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1706/574359) comment.

I read about bridge on wikipedia and I understood that IT just extends the network. Does it mean that, connected 2nd computer will need credentials to access the network? Or will it be connected right away?

I want to do the same setup described in the link. But I am in a network which requires specific certificates to connect. I want to connect 2nd pc over 1st pc without needing additional certificates.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a bridge with a router. But in both cases, the device may implement authentication although this is uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is gone, but the problem is that you use the term "connect to the network" for two completely different mechanisms.

The certificate-based access to the network is probably some form of NAC. That works as follows (picture from Wikipedia):

[image]

Your bridge will not help you in this.

However, to receive the EAP-request identity, there must be some form of connection between the authenticator (most probably a switch) and the supplicant (the PC). The bridge will allow you to create this kind of network connectivity.

Another word of caution. There is a reason why organisations adopt Network Access Control with certificates. It is almost always a part of their security architecture. If you could connect a second PC without certificate, that would be circumventing the security measures, which may have serious consequences for you. Don't be too naive about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH to connect to the second machine. It will open a shell.
SSH normally require authentication but if you copy a key from machine 1 to machine 2, you will be able to connect without authentication.