# Why are nameservers the same between two computers sharing connection?

Tags: networking

In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1936/674, Why is the nameserver on PC2 set to be the same as that on PC1?

> Asuming that:
>
> - ...
> - 10.0.0.2 is the IP address for the nameserver used by PC1 ( `cat /etc/resolve.conf` on PC1 )
>
> **ON PC1:**
>
> ...
> **ON PC2:**
>
> **eth0** is the interface that connects to PC1
>
> ```
> ...
> # specify nameserver
> echo "nameserver 10.0.0.2" >> /etc/resolve.conf
> ```

Comment: You need to have a nameserver entry to be able to resolve names<>IP and probably as dNS protocol is over UDP and not TCP it cannot be resolve. BTW it's /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @admstg, DNS works over both UDP and TCP

Comment: @ilkkachu from wikipedia : DNS typically uses UDP and port 53. The maximum packet size used is 512 bytes. If a response exceeds this size, the standard provides that the request must be sent back to TCP port 53. **This case is, however, rare and avoided, and firewalls often block TCP port 53.**

Comment: @admstg, it might be relatively rare. And yet, what I said about DNS working over TCP is still true. Of course it won't work if some idiot "security" buffoon goes and blocks it, sigh. Anyway, I'm not even sure how the UDP vs. TCP question is relevant to the nameserver configuration, since usually one just configures the IP address (as above also).

Answer (score 2):

Rereading that link, it sounds like that's the only available nameserver (or thats the nameserver they want to use) and that PC2 is using PC1 for a connection to the nameserver.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, they don't have to be the same.

If PC1 is already using 10.0.0.2 as a nameserver and has a fully working internet connection, you already know that 10.0.0.2 *works* as a nameserver.

If you had a reason to, you could choose to specify some other nameserver, e.g. a public nameserver like Google's 8.8.8.8, Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 or Quad9's 9.9.9.9.

But if you already know that 10.0.0.2 works to your satisfaction, and have no particular reason to use some other service, why change something that works?

(Also, note that writing `nameserver x.x.x.x` configuration lines to `/etc/resolv.conf` is no longer as universal a way to configure nameservers on Linux/Unix as it was back when the answer linked in the question was written. Depending on PC2's configuration, you might use one of NetworkManager's various user interfaces, use `resolvectl` or edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` instead.)

Comment: And since PC2 already needs PC1 to access the network, one possible configuration would be for PC1 to also act as a DNS resolver for PC2 to use.